# Based on date and time, show/hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show and hide an element on a page based on multiple dates and times. For instance, I have an alert box that I want to show for the following dates 4/28, 4/29, and 4/30 between the hours of 9 am to 12 pm PST. And hide for the remaining hours. The posted code works for an open and closing time but I am unsure how I can add multiple dates. Or I'm just missing something.

Edit: I suck at jQuery/JavaScript.

**HTML**

```
<div class="open openstatus">Open</div>
<div class="closed openstatus">Closed</div>
```

**JS**

```
var now = new Date(),
  currentDay = now.getDay(),
  openTime = new Date(
    now.getFullYear(),
    now.getMonth(),
    now.getDate(),
    13,
    02
  ),
  closeTime = new Date(
    now.getFullYear(),
    now.getMonth(),
    now.getDate(),
    13,
    03
  ),
  open = now.getTime() > openTime.getTime() && now.getTime() < closeTime.getTime();

  if (currentDay !== 6 && currentDay !== 0 && open) {
      $('.openstatus').toggle();
  }
```

Comment: Two things - 1. You might want to use something like moment.js because the date format you're using will be specific to local timezone
2. In your if condition, you might just want to use `.show()` instead of `.toggle()` as the condition is satisfied for the former and then use an `else` to `.hide()`

Comment: @RahulDwivedi Thank you for your suggestions. I'll take them into account.

Comment: @RahulDwivedi If I were to use MomentJS, would I replace my `now.getDay()` with `moment().date()`? I'm sorry, I'm not sure how that would be added.

Comment: `moment.js` has got different ways to handle these requirements.
https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Comment: @alysus See the complete answer below and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="alertBox">My alert box</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function myFunc(){

    var d = new Date(); //client Date
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset()); //To get current GMT time
    d.setHours(d.getHours() - 8); // This is time in PST

    var day = d.getDay(),
        month = d.getMonth(),
        hours = d.getHours(),
        dateOfMonth = d.getDate();

    var prohibbittedMonth = 4;
    var prohibbittedDates =[28, 29, 30];
    var showAlertBox = false;

    if(day === 0 || day === 6){
        showAlertBox = true; // If the day is Saturday or Sunday
    }else if(month = prohibbittedMonth && prohibbittedDates.includes(dateOfMonth) && !(hours >= 0 && hours <9)){
        showAlertBox = true;     
    }
     // You may combine the above two condition in a single line. I have just separated them for better readability.

    if(!showAlertBox){
        document.getElementById('alertBox').style.display = "none";  //You may use your jquery here if you like
    }else{
        document.getElementById('alertBox').style.display = ""; //You may use your jquery here if you like
    }
}

myFunc();
```

Comment: I apologize for the late response. Thank you for the extended answer. If possible, can you explain the difference between your code compared to the one I posted? I know you spoke of timezones... so, someone viewing my page in Arkansas would see it in their timezone? Sorry, I'm just trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: @alyus Here are few things I have done that was missing:
1. I have adjusted the timezone so that it doesn't affect the result based on the timezone in which your application is viewed
2. Simplified the logic to make it more scalable - say in future, you should be able to add multiple prohibited dates just by adding them in the `prohibittedDates` array. Similarly for month as well.
3. Your `toggle` logic might not work, I suspected. Have taken care of the same in my code.
4. the code as when to show alertbox looks cleaner with my code. 
Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Cant't you add sth like this 
currentDate=now.getDate();

if (currentDay !== 6 && currentDay !== 0 && open && **(currentDate==28||currentDate==29||currentDate==30)**)

This checks if the currentDate is either 28 or 29 or 30.